# Conflict between tensorflow/PIL/pillow and scikit-image?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda, spyder, scikit-image

I am tying to rebuild my computer to run Spyder in a tensorflow environment for some image processing.  In the past this worked and I had scikit-image working fully in that environment, and accessible from Spyder.  Something has changed.  I have:
1) re-installed Anaconda
2) re-installed tensorflow in a conda environment
3) installed libraries as needed, including Spyder.

Then I start Spyder from the Conda navigator, in the tensorflow environment.  This seems to work, I can import tensorflow, keras, pandas, sklearn, etc.  But skimage only works partially.  for example:

```
    import skimage
```

works fine. But,

```
    import skimage.io as io
```

does not. The error comes out as 'from PIL import Image' Is this something about PIL/pillow not co-existing in the same environment?  Can this be fixed easily or should I just use opencv for image io?  I have tried other modules in skimage and they all import.  So using another package to open an image would not be the end of the world, but it would be nice to get the entirety of skimage working.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to `conda install pillow`? I don't know why it would be missing but that seems to be what is missing.

Comment: Pillow is listed in my tensorflow environment. Tried to rebuild everything today. Even to get to the status above, I had to downgrade skimage from 0.14.2. To 0.14.0. more recent versions would not even let me import skimage.  I put an issue in on GitHub.

Comment: Ok after multiple re-installs everything seems to work.  I still don't understand what happened, but everything now works.